# Impossibility of polynomial approximation

Tags: complex-analysis

This is exercise 12.6 in David Ullrich's *Complex Made Simple*. He has discussed many ways to prove the existence of polynomial approximations to functions in the complex plane, but not how to show such approximations are impossible in certain cases, which is the point of the problem. I have an idea, but I'm unsure about its validity.

**Problem:** Fix $M<0$. Let $f(z)$ be defined on $\mathbb C$ so that $f(0)=1$ and $f(z)=0$ for $z\neq 0$. Show there does not exist a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_n(z) =f(z)$ if we require $|p_n(z)|<M$ for all $z$ with $|z|\le 1$ for every $n$.

**Proposed Solution:** let $\gamma$ be the unit circle, traversed once. Consider the rational functions $p_n/z$. Using the dominated convergence theorem, permissible because the $f(z)$ are uniformly bounded along $\gamma$, we have

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_\gamma p_n(z)/z \ dz = \int_\gamma \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_n(z)/z \ dz = \int_\gamma f(z)/z = 0.$$

But the limit on the left is just the limits of the residues of $p_n(z)/z$ at $0$, which is (modulo a $2\pi i$) the constant term in the power series expansion of $p_n(z)$ at $0$, or $p_n(0)$, And we are given this goes to $1$. We get $1=0$, and the contradiction shows the impossibility of the specified approximation.

Is this correct? And is there a better or more elementary way? Ullrich makes a point of avoiding theorems requiring measure theory to prove, like the dominated convergence theorem, so I suspect there is.

Comment: It looks good to me like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this: The sequence $p_n$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of holomorphic functions on the (open) unit disc, and therefore a normal family (Montel's theorem). If they converge to $f$, they must converge uniformly on compact sets along some subsequence. But then $f$ would be continuous (indeed, holomorphic), and it isn't.

Comment: Excellent. This might have been what the author had in mind.